# How to forward a parameterlist

Tags: java, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I have declared an interface `Listable`, a `Node` containing a `Listable`, and a  `SinglyLinkedList` containing Nodes. The `SinglyLinkedList` contains a `search()` method, which makes use of the method `matches()` in `Listable`. I want to have `Listable` as general as possible, so the amount of arguments in `matches()` should be arbitrary. 
`search()` returns a new `SinglyLinkedList` containing only those elements of `this` that match.

Look at the following implementation:

```
interface Listable {
    // ...
    boolean matches(Object... matchesArgs);
    // ...
}

class Node {
   Listable data;
   Node next;
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    // ...
    public SinglyLinkedList search(Object... searchArgs) {
        // ...
        somewhere: [someNode].data.matches(searchArgs)
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This does not work, because `matchesArgs` only has one element: the array `searchArgs`. I want it to equal `searchArgs`, not `[searchArgs]`.

I do not want to unpack the array in the implementation of `matches()`, because that would require passing an array of arguments whenever you use `matches()`, and it also tries to handle a problem somewhere it is not created.

In my eyes, the problem is that `searchArgs` is packed into another array when forwarding it to `matches()`. Instead of passing this array, I would like to pass its elements as parameters.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Your code gives an warning because it's ambiguous. The root of this ambiguity is the use of `Object` in your variadic method. Consider modeling your system such that your method doesn't receive the poor `Object` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that passing `searchArgs` as an argument to `matches` results in the argument being wrapped by another array. Take this sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThat(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    }

    public static void doThat(Object... varargs) {
        doThis(varargs);
    }

    public static void doThis(Object... varargs) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(varargs));
    }
}
```

The output is the expected `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: you're totally right... I actually forgot an argument when calling search() ... and when I saw the error (I had implemented some exceptions matches), I immediately thought about the described problem instead of checking my parameters when calling search() first... This is embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: Not embarrassing at all. All the best with what you're trying to code up!

Answer (score 0):

> that would require passing an array of arguments whenever you use matches()

But you specify in the signature of the method, that it accepts array of variable length. In calling code, there is nothing that will stop you from passing one or some values. Inside matches method it will be an array

Comment: I have edited the question to make the problem more clear... I know that `matchesArgs` is an array, but the problem is, it only has one element: the array `searchArgs`. I want it to equal `searchArgs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, your problem can  be reduced to:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(1, 2, 3);
    test(new Integer [] {1, 2, 3});
  }

  public static void test(Object... args) {
    System.out.println("Length: " + args.length);
  }
}
```

This code emits the following warning:

> warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter

The problem is clear. Java can't decide if the array is to be spread out or to be passed as the first argument.

You solve this problem by using the proper type.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(1, 2, 3);
    test(new Integer [] {1, 2, 3});
  }
                       // here!
  public static void test(Integer... args) {
    System.out.println("Length: " + args.length);
  }
}
```

Now this code has no ambiguity and compiles just fine. The output is:

```
Length: 3
Length: 3
```

You should make good use of the type system.